# Is there a way that Appium can focus to new window tab in Safari?

Tags: ios, selenium, appium, ipados

I'm doing my task to automate a specific website's performance by using Appium. I'm testing the iPadOS(iOS 14.x and above) and the website has a new tab feature when a button is clicked. Now, the problem is that when I tried to use getWindowHandles and sorts of that nothing happens. Here's my code:

`String url = "https://demoqa.com/browser-windows";`
 `driver.get(url);`

```
    try {
        System.out.println(1321);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); 
        String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
        
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabButton\"]")).isDisplayed());
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabButton\"]")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); 
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
         //getting all the handles currently available
        Set<String> handles=driver.getWindowHandles();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(handles.size());
        for(String actual: handles)
        {
            
         if(!actual.equalsIgnoreCase(currentHandle))
         {
             //switching to the opened tab
             driver.switchTo().window(actual); 
         }
        }
```

Output:
**1321
ToolsQA
true
ToolsQA
ToolsQA
1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you do this  :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabButton\"]")).click();
```

you need to switch to the new tab/window

**Code  :**

```
ArrayList<String> handles = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabButton\"]")).isDisplayed());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabButton\"]")).click();
driver.switchTo().window(handles.get(1));
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/browser-windows");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabButton\"]")).isDisplayed());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabButton\"]")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
ArrayList<String> handles = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(handles.get(1));
System.out.println("Switched");
System.out.println(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("sampleHeading"))).getText());
```

Comment: Sure, let me know if you face any issue

Comment: I'm getting this error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Did it mean that the problem is the tabButton wasn't clicked at all?

Comment: @JuvinDC : I have updated the code above, you can try the new code from udpate 1 section

Comment: Sure thing my friend

Comment: I got the same result. note that I'm using Appium and below is my capabilities used:

deviceName=iPad Pro 5g
platformName=iOS
platformVersion=14.5
platform=iPhone
appiumVersion=1.21.0
browserName=safari
automationName=XCUITest

Comment: Appium should not be a problem, can you try the same in chrome for testing purpose ?

Comment: yay, it worked using chrome. So the problem would be on Safari?

Comment: Yeah could be,  I see this issue quite often in Safari.. try switching to chrome always get the job done.